# How can you select unique values with MySQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table full of messages between users, and I want to select the last message from each user where the userFrom is not my user(4), however if the last message to another user(userTo) is the last message between my user(4) and another user then that should be the value for that msg in the return records.

TABLE messages

```
id|userFrom|userTo|msg
-------------------------
1 |  4     | 9    |msg 1    
2 |  9     | 4    |msg 2    
3 |  4     | 63   |msg 1    
4 |  63    | 4    |msg 2    
5 |  4     | 9    |msg 3    
6 |  9     | 4    |msg 4    
7 |  9     | 4    |msg 5
8 |  63    | 4    |msg 3
```

My end goal is to use the data to show a list of messages from unique users where each row is a different user and it shows the last message between my user and that user(for visual reference i'm trying to create something like Facebook messages)

How i would like the above table data returned

```
id|userFrom|msg
-------------------------
7 |  9     |msg 5    
8 |  63    |msg 3
```

i need the userFrom to be unique so i can extend the query to do additional joins to get the actual varchar username from the users table where the userFrom is some user but not my own user.

Comment: Where is id 8 coming from?

Comment: You can use a subquery to select the last message for a user.

Comment: @kbball i forgot to include it.. i edited since you viewed to include the 8th row of data.

Comment: Have you tried something? Post your code. `GROUP BY` doesn't help, btw.

Comment: SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY userFrom,userTo, i'm really not sure what to do to get the results i'm looking for which is why i posted the question

Comment: @WilliamWorley What happens if a user is part of two different conversations? And why do you need 'msg' in the msg column?  Why can't it just be a number?

Comment: `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` in the same query is, most of the times, invalid SQL. And when it is valid, there are better ways to get the same result. Which is not the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option with `least` and `greatest`:

```
select id, userfrom, userto, msg
from messages m join (
  select max(id) maxid
  from messages
  group by  least(userfrom, userto), greatest(userfrom, userto)
  ) t on m.id = t.maxid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77543d/1)

---

BTW -- I assume your expected results are incorrect. You don't have `id = 8` in your sample data.

Comment: Your solution works however the data returned i need as i'm joining additional tables in the query which i have left out of this question as they don't really relate, but to be transparent i need join a users table on userFrom/userTo on the returned data so like JOIN users u on u.id=messages.userFrom

Comment: @WilliamWorley -- not sure what your comment means -- you can easily `join` more tables to this result...

Comment: not if i don't know what the user i need to join on is, as i don't want to filter the results in php once the data is returned from mysql

Comment: @WilliamWorley -- sounds like you need to return the user names as well?  If so, you can `join` to your `users` table multiple times: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/698ea9/1

Comment: seems to brute force, i don't need to know anything about user 4 i just need to know which users i have messages with and what was the last message that was either received or sent to that user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT messages.id, messages.userFrom, messages.msg
FROM messages INNER JOIN
(SELECT userFrom, max(id) AS mxid
FROM messages
GROUP BY userFrom) sub
ON messages.id = sub.mxid
WHERE messages.UserFrom <> 4
```

Comment: this only returns one record, i need all records for each different user as the userFrom and the msg being the last message either from this user or my user

Comment: I must be confused as to what the question is asking. I thought you only wanted "the last message from each user."

Comment: Doesn't the query return one row per user? And the sample result in the question also contains one row per user.

Comment: @mm759 Exactly, the output is the last message from each user and matches the desired output in the question

Comment: @WilliamWorley If there is another case that is not covered by the query, make sure that is included in the sample data so that we can right a better query if needed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserMessage](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [userFrom] [int] NOT NULL,
    [userTo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [msg] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into UserMessage values(1,4,9,'msg 1')
insert into UserMessage values(2,9,4,'msg 2')
insert into UserMessage values(3,4,63,'msg 1')
insert into UserMessage values(4,63,4,'msg 2')
insert into UserMessage values(5,4,9,'msg 3')
insert into UserMessage values(6,9,4,'msg 4')
insert into UserMessage values(7,9,4,'msg 5')
insert into UserMessage values(8,63,4,'msg 3')

SELECT lastMesageFrom.*, um.msg
FROM
(
select max(id) as id,UserFrom from UserMessage
where UserTo = 4 
Group by UserFrom
)as lastMesageFrom
Left Outer join UserMessage um on um.id = lastMesageFrom.id
```

[image]

EDIT: Verified with MySQL:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1045b/1

Comment: This excludes any messages where my user(4) might have sent a message to some other user but that user never replied meaning i could have a single message with id=9, userFrom=4, userTo=20, msg=msg 1 and this result should be retruned like 9,20,msg 1

Comment: please see where your query fails as userFrom is user 9 twice and it shouldn't be, it should be userFrom=9, msg="msg 6" http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/deb4fe

Comment: Actually from and to user should be paired with a key to aggregate to get the result as expected.  Here is the simple logic I've used to produce a pair key, but this is not strong enough, this should be optimized with better logic.  But still it will work.

Check this filder 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccc21f/1

Actual query is

SELECT messages.* from 
messages inner join
(
SELECT max(id) as maxid,
userfrom+userto as pair 
from messages
  group by pair
 )t 
 on t.maxid = messages.id

Comment: @William Worley - Did you check my latest comment? does it help?

Answer (score -1):

You must read the difference between where and having clause.

First, filter your records by WHERE clause (where userFrom!=4)
Then use the group by
And finally filter the messages that were sent to you by HAVING clause (having userTo=4)

Comment: tried SELECT * FROM messages where userFrom!=4 GROUP BY userFrom,userTo having userTo=4 but this didn't return the right results as it only retruned the rows that i'm not the userFrom with the wrong msg

Comment: Its like doing someone's homework! You must use GROUP BY userFrom and in SELECT it should be userFrom, max(ID). Once you get the ID, make another select query to get the message.